# $_SESSION blocked in the connection page

Tags: php, html, authentication, session-cookies, account

My site recently put online, I realize that it has a very problematic bug, forcing me to put it into maintenance.

I have a login form that I’ve been able to fix. I thought at first that was the problem. However, by focusing more on the problem, I realize that the `$_SESSION['auth']` session remains stuck in the login page. Wherever I go, it disappears.
Below you will find the codes of different pages as well as the "account.php" page which contains a redirection to the login page when the user is not logged in. The login page is supposed to send the logged-in user to the "account.php" page, but this one, not finding the session, returns it to the login page.
More simply, whatever page I’m going to, I’m disconnected.

connexion.php : https://pastebin.com/wxCHw3Nk

account.php : https://pastebin.com/xngQVAQN

includes/needed.php :

```php
<?php

session_set_cookie_params(["SameSite" => "Strict"]); //none, lax, strict
session_set_cookie_params(["Secure" => "true"]); //false, true
session_set_cookie_params(["HttpOnly" => "true"]); //false, true
session_start(); //everything before this

if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
    session_start();
}
require_once 'functions.php';

reconnect_from_cookie();

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
?>
```

includes/functions.php : https://pastebin.com/Bn476N29

includes/header.php : https://pastebin.com/c3ZATAwQ

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Can you share the code triggering the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really know how to debug such a program. I also don't know where's the bug from